# Extend an XML Schema via the <any> element

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

The `<any>` element in an XML Schema definition allows a schema to be extended by another schema.

I tried to follow the example given at https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_complex_any.asp.

However, as long as the `children` element is not namespace qualified IntelliJ will give me the validation error message "The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'children'". I can remove this error by adding 'xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com"' to the children element. While this makes a lot of sense I would really like the possibility of "drop-in" extensions without the need to specify the namespace. Is there some hidden feature I am missing? Or is the example flawed and you always need to specify the namespace explicitly?

I am using IntelliJ to edit and validate the XML Schema and XML file with XML Schema 1.1 activated.

I complemented the `family.xsd` fragment from the example as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com"
           targetNamespace="http://www.microsoft.com"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="persons">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="person" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:any minOccurs="0"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>

            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The question is: Is the W3Schools example flawed or should it work without specifying the namespace for the 'children' element?

Thank you for hints and ideas!

Comment: Please don't tell us it doesn't work. Tell us how it fails. What requirement do you have that this schema fails to satisfy?

Comment: I am sorry, I should have been more concrete. I updated the question. As of now, I just want to clearly understand the 'any' mechanism in the context of extending one schema with elements defined in another schema.

Comment: Thanks for adding the failure symptoms. That will make it easier to see what the problem is. It appears to be in the area of "processContents" rather than namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

By "schema-qualified" I suspect you mean "namespace-qualified".

If you want to allow elements in any namespace or none, use `<xs:any namespace="##any"/>`

#### LATER

`namespace='##any'` is indeed the default, so that doesn't appear to be the problem.

Now you've told us the error message, that points to `processContents`. The default for `processContents` is `strict`, which means an element is allowed only if there is a global element declaration (and it must be valid against that declaration).

In the W3Schools example the instance document has an `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute for the namespace of the `children` element that points to a schema containing a declaration of that element. Because `processContents="strict"`, that schema is needed. It doesn't matter what the namespace is, so long as a global element declaration exists.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You're completely right, I meant namespace-qualified and edited the question accordingly. As I understand, ##any is the default value for the namespace attribute. It will allow me to use elements from another namespace than the one the original schema is about. Now the question remains: In the W3Schools example there doesn't seem to be an explicit namespace-qualification. I cannot reproduce due to the "no declaration can be found" error. The question is: Am I doing something wrong or is the example missing the namespace qualification?

Comment: Thanks for the LATER answer. We come nearer to the core issue of my question, namely "global element declarations". If I understand you correctly, you propose to set the `processContents` to `lax` on the `<any>` element. If I do this, the validation error will disappear. However, IntelliJ then shows that the children.xsd schema is unused. And in fact I can now add any contents into the `children` element without any validation error. What I had wished for is an automatic recognition that children.xsd defines the children element and a validation against children.xsd for that element.

Comment: With lax validation, it's not true that you can add any content without any error. You can either add an element that has no schema definition, or you can add an element that conforms to its schema definition; you can't add an element that has a schema definition but doesn't conform to it.

Comment: True, However, my point is exactly the case where I add an element without a namespace qualification: It will always be accepted without any validation attempt when using lax validation. This is the exact original question: Can I reach validation against a globally specified schema without given the `children` element this namespace locally. It appears the answer is `no`.